# Microsoft drivers or manufacturer drivers?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-update

I do a few Windows 10 installs for my customers from time to time.
Many computers will work fine with all of the device drivers from Windows update.
My question is... Is it better to install the latest drivers from the manufacturer, or is it ok to leave the Microsoft provided drivers?
Do the manufacturer's drivers provide better performance and stability?
Especially for chipset and graphics drivers.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is really just my personal opinion, but based on many years of doing this type of thing.

Chipset drivers - let Windows find them.
Certainly never trust "Driver Helper" apps of any sort to do this.

GPU drivers - get them from Intel/AMD/NVidia
Whether you let those install all the bells & whistles or just the drivers is up to you. For stability, just the drivers, though updates will then have to be manual. Some of the ancillary *gumph* that's installed is a waste of space unless you're a gamer - & can actually hinder some operations.

Answer (score 2):

The drivers that Microsoft provides are still provided from the hardware manufacturer, however, they are just a stripped-down version.

So the drivers provided from Microsoft are perfectly fine, you just won't get all the added features that you normally would if you used the manufacturer's drivers.

For example, if you have an NVIDIA graphics card and you use the Microsoft graphics driver, you get the NVIDIA Control Panel feature.